# Generate all possible combinations after grouping by in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cartesian-product

Let's say I have a table called my_table in this format

```
key | animal
------------
1   |  Cat
2   |  Cat
3   |  Cat
4   |  Dog
5   |  Dog
```

I would like to get a table of this format

```
animal | key1 | key2
--------------------
Cat    |  1   |  2
Cat    |  1   |  3
Cat    |  2   |  3
Dog    |  4   |  5
```

Note that I DON'T want to use join from the beginning because it's very expensive for the size of the table that I have; that's to say I don't wanna do

```
SELECT m1.animal, m1.key AS key1, m2.key AS key2
FROM my_table m1
INNER JOIN my_table m2
 ON (m1.key < m2.key)
WHERE m1.animal = m2.animal
```

I would like to do something like GROUP BY animal or PARTITION BY animal, and then generate all possible combinations for the key column inside the grouped animal col, because I don't wanna do unnecessary computations of combining keys for different animals.

EDIT: Note that |keys| >> |animals|

Comment: If you have the proper indexes to support the JOIN, then that solution is better than any other solution. The index for the query you show above should be on the pair of columns `(animal, key)` in that order.

Comment: But I only wanna generate combinations for each group, not for the whole table! If I wanna do the usual join it's very computationally expensive! That's why I'm asking for an alternative that might be faster

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @BillKarwin, there is no need for indexes. Hash Join will do the job just fine.

Comment: @Guess601, it seems you are under a false assumption that the join is going to happen based on the inequality condition and then the filter will happen  based on the equality condition, so "No", it is the other way around.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz as far as I know JOINs happen before WHEREs in the order of execution, right?

Comment: No, the order depends on the execution plan, which sometimes can be very different from what you would expect. In your case the optimizer will most likely use the equality condition to execute the join. If you don't have indexes and you data volume is large enough it is going to be an Hash Join.

Comment: P.S. you should tag your post with the relevant DB / SQL engine

Comment: So, if I do a JOIN like "ON (m1.key < m2.key) AND (m1.animal = m2.animal)" then the optimizer will choose the condition that makes the execution time faster? interesting!

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Hash joins (in MySQL at least, but I suppose in any implementation) are used for equi-joins, but this example uses an inequality condition.

Comment: @Guess601 A compound index can be used for both conditions at the same time, which should be superior to either single-column index.

Comment: Most if not all optimizers will do it in anyway. This equality condition has the exact same semantics whether it is in the WHERE clause or the JOIN clause (but it would be considered a better style to put it as a JOIN condition). @BillKarwin - that also answers your comment

Comment: For most optimizers, if not all, it won't matter.

Comment: ... and you still didn't tag your post with the relevant DB / SQL engine

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz didn't find the tag!

Comment: What were you looking for?

Comment: I just added it. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I agree I expect SQL optimizers to figure out the right index whether you put the conditions in the JOIN clause or in the WHERE clause. But I can't speak for Snowflake specifically.

Answer (score 1):

So lets use some data:

lets create some tables of animals and keys:

```
CREATE TABLE data_100Kx10 as  
 SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            seq8() as animal
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100000))
    ) a, (
        SELECT 
            seq8() as key
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100))
    ) b;

CREATE TABLE data_100Kx100 as  
 SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            seq8() as animal
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100000))
    ) a, (
        SELECT 
            seq8() as key
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100))
    ) b;

CREATE TABLE data_1Mx10 as  
 SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            seq8() as animal
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100000))
    ) a, (
        SELECT 
            seq8() as key
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100))
    ) b;
```

so those take on an xtra small warehouse

| name | rows | time to create |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100Kx10 | 1,000,000 | 1.4s |
| 100Kx100 | 10,000,000 | 2.5s |
| 1Mx10 | 10,000,000 | 2.5s |

nice now lets compare two ways of querying that data:

How I would write the join (will call `= <`)

```
SELECT sum(animal), sum(key1), sum(key2) FROM(
    SELECT m1.animal, m1.key AS key1, m2.key AS key2
    FROM data_100Kx100 m1
    INNER JOIN data_100Kx100 m2
     ON m1.animal = m2.animal and m1.key < m2.key   
);
```

verse how you wrote the join (will call `< =`)

```
SELECT m1.animal, m1.key AS key1, m2.key AS key2
FROM data_100Kx100 m1
INNER JOIN data_100Kx100 m2
 ON (m1.key < m2.key)
WHERE m1.animal = m2.animal
```

| form | table | time | rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| = < | 100Kx10 | 2.7s | 4.5M |
| < = | 100Kx10 | 2.8s | 4.5M |
| = < | 100Kx100 | 120s | 495M |
| < = | 100Kx100 | 50ms* | 4.5M |

- just proves they are the same query.

But the point is is slow "to fetch large amounts of data" we can see this but changing to summing all the results:

```
SELECT sum(animal), sum(key1), sum(key2) FROM(
    SELECT m1.animal, m1.key AS key1, m2.key AS key2
    FROM data_100Kx10 m1
    INNER JOIN data_100Kx10 m2
     ON m1.animal = m2.animal and m1.key < m2.key   
);
```

gives:

| SUM(ANIMAL) | SUM(KEY1) | SUM(KEY2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 224,997,750,000 | 12,000,000 | 28,500,000 |

| table | time |
| --- | --- |
| 100Kx10 | 0.08s |
| 100Kx100 | 0.1s |
| 1Mx10 | 1.4s |

So these tables are small, but if you are moving all rows around, it's slow, but if you are doing something meaningful with the data, full table joins are not really that slow.

Which is to say, write the SQL and if it's slow work out can it go faster, verse avoiding doing something, because "we think it's slow"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I edited the question to indicate that the number of keys is much larger than the number of animals. So what do you think I should do in this case to speed up the process?